# Could I write a template class within a macro?

Tags: c++, templates, macros

I have a template class `A`, I will know the `T` depends on which class call it.

For example, there are 10 classes will use the class A, one of 10 class is called `file1`.

Could I write the code as shown in the class `file1`?

```
class D;

template<typename T>
class A
{
  protected：
      int a;
      int b;
      static T *ptr;
  public:
      static void set_a(int aa){ a = aa; }
      static D *create()
        { return new T(); }
};
```

could I do something like the followings

```
 class file1
 {
    #define T file1   
     A<T>   
    #undef

     .....other data member vs member function
 }


 class file2
 {
    #define T file2   
     A<T>      
    #undef

     .....other data member vs member function
 }
```

the orginal code is something like the followings:

where the anotherMacro1 is

```
#define anotherMacro1(method)\
  public:\
  static return_type functionname(passingtype *ptr1, passingtype *ptr2)\
  {\
  return ((T *)ptr1)->method(ptr2);\
  }
```

======================================================================

A is also a macro

like

```
 #define A \
  protected：\
      int a;\
      int b;\
      static T *ptr;\
  public:\
      static void set_a(int aa){ a = aa; }\
      static D *create()\
        { return new T(); }
```

==============================================================================

```
   class file1_orginal
{
  #define T file1_orginal
   A()
   anotherMacro1(passingValue);
   anotherMacro2(passingValue);
  #endif

   .....other data member vs member function
}
```

First I want to remove the macro in A, So i use class A to replace the macro A.

Comment: `virtual static` function? Class which is called "using"? `#undef` without macro name? Is it C++?

Comment: _'one of 10 class is called "using"'_ `using` is a c++ keyword!! That particularly won't compile ...

Comment: Why not directly pass the class as template argument? I dont really get what you want to achieve.

Comment: besides the fact that `using` is a c++ keyword, are you trying to do `A<using>`?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about lacking a minimal understanding of the language.

Comment: This code makes no sense. You probably can get it to compile, but it will still make no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, yes, you could do this.  Practically speaking I'm not sure I see any value in:

```
#define T file1
A<T>
#undef T
```

versus:

```
A<file1>
```

However, you've definitely made the whole thing less readable.  What's the point?  This seems like a solution in search of a problem.  I can't imagine a problem to which this is the solution.

---

Ok, so given your example macros, I would suggest progressively refactoring towards templates.  The use of 'protected' visibility inside the macro is questionable but we'll keep it.  I'd start with this:

```
template<class CRTP>    //Curiously Recurring Template Pattern
class A {
    protected:
        int a;
        int b;
        static CRTP *ptr;
    public:
        void set_a(int aa){ a = aa; }
        static D *create() { return new CRTP(); }  //D is a base class?
};
```

and then:

```
class file1 : public A<file1> {
    #define T file1
        anotherMacro1(passingValue);
        anotherMacro2(passingValue);
    #undef T
    ...
};
```

This uses the [curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to transclude the members from A.  I've never tried this with protected members in the base class, but I seem to remember that protected members are inherited and carry forward as protected members for future inheritance.  I'd consider the need for these protected members poor design anyway and would refactor them to accessor functions, but I think this does what you want.  Later you can work on refactoring the contents of anotherMacro1 and anotherMacro2.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I am trying to remove all of the macro in the source code. But there are too many nested macro. I know the A<file1 > works well,  but #define A<T> \ another_macro\#undef. In "another_macro" I need the "T" either. So I should to remove the macro step by step.

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding what you mean.  Can you edit your question to include some of the original macros to illustrate the multi-layered macros you are trying to replace?  That might help clarify what problem it is you are solving.

Comment: I have add the original macro. Could you help me with it?

Comment: looking at your definition of anotherMacro1, I'd encourage you to read about std::bind and std::function (or the Boost implementations if you don't have C++11).  Using function objects would probably eliminate the need for the static forwarding function that anotherMacro1 is creating.